# Dockerfile ADD variable not expandable

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cloud

I am setting up a docker image, in the dockerfile I have an ADD command where source of the ADD command is a variable.
Dockerfile takes a build argument, I want to use that arg as source of the ADD command.
But ADD command is not expanding the variable and I get an error

Please share any workaround that comes in your mind

```
FROM ubuntu

ARG source_dir
RUN echo ${source_dir}
ADD ${source_dir} ./ContainerDir
```

Build command

```
docker build . -t image --build-arg source_dir=/home/john/Desktop/
data
```

Error

```
Step 3/3 : ADD ${source_dir} ./ContainerDir ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder311119108/home/john/Desktop/
data: no such file or directory
```

However, the directory (/home/john/Desktop/
data) exists

Comment: better to show your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, the variable expanded and complained that you don't have the path in your build context:

```
stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder311119108/a/b/c: no such file or directory
```

In your example, the build context is `.` (the current directory) so you need `a/b/c` in the current directory for this to not error. That also need to not be in any `./.dockerignore` file if you have one.

---

From your second edit:

```
docker build . -t image --build-arg source_dir=/home/john/Desktop/data
```

It looks like you are trying to include a directory inside your build from outside of the build context. That is explicitly not allowed in docker builds. All files needed for the `ADD` and `COPY` commands need to be included in your context, and the entire content of the context is sent to the build server in the first step, so you want to keep this small (rather than sending the entire home directory). The source is always relative to this context, so `/home` is looking for `./home` since your context is `.` in the build command.

The fix is to move the data directory to be a sub directory of `.` where you are building your docker images. You can also switch to `COPY` since there is no functionality of `ADD` that you need.

---

Disclaimer: there are two pieces of over simplification here:

1. The `COPY` command can include files from different contexts using the `--from` option to `COPY`.
2. The entire context is sent before the build starts with the classic build command. The newer BuildKit implementation is much more selective about how much and what parts of the context to send.

Comment: Thanks for  the reply, where does the prefix /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder311119108 comes from?

Comment: @Madan The build context is tar'd and sent to the engine. Builds do not happen directly in your local directory, the docker engine can be on a remote server using `$DOCKER_HOST`